# WPFDataGrid behaves strangely with DataGridTemplateColumn sorting after editing the cell content

Tags: wpf, sorting, datagrid, datagridtemplatecolumn, emptydatatext

I am facing a problem with WPFDataGrid. I have bound my DataGrid to XML data. I am using DataGridTemplateColumn for all the columns. 
After the initial data is loaded everything(like sorting, etc) works fine. Then once I edit some cell say a **TextBox** in template column and then try to sort the grid, the cell which contains the TextBox  have empty data!! (I mean the TextBox becomes empty). This happens whenever I edit any cell.

Is it a bug in WPFDataGrid? I am sure many people who use template columns would have faced it. Urgent help required !!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to add this to my DataGrid declaration

```
 SelectionUnit="Cell"
```

It solved my problem !!!